# how to pass variable to phtml file in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, phtml

form

```
<input  type="text"  class="input-text required-entry validate-number form-control validate-zero-or-greater" id= "checkout-cart-credit-amount-textboxone"  title="<?php echo $this->__('Gift Card Credit') ?>" name="customer_creditone" />
```

controller

```
public function getTextValueAction ()
    {
    $input_amount = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customer_creditone');
    //echo $input_amount.'<br>';

    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
    }
```

controller is working fine me.
 how to call controller variable to phtml file

Answer (score 7):

you can pass variable from controller like

`$this->getLayout()->getBlock('block.name')->assign('somestring', $variable)`

and in phtml you can simply use like

`<?php echo $variable ?>`

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by Mage registry :

```
Mage::register('custom_value', $monthly_budget);
```

and then get it in phtml :

```
$monthly_budget = Mage::registry('custom_value');
```

Another way using session :

In controller set value:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setYourDataVal($data);
```

In phtml get Value:

```
$data = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getYourDataVal();
```

Comment: i did not get solution ....

Comment: i used in phtml file <?php  $data =  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEndBalance($data);
   echo $data;
   ?>

Comment: and in controller Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEndBalance($data);

Comment: In controller Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEndBalance($data); and in phtml <?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getEndBalance(); ?>

Comment: i did not get solution

Comment: Did you flush cache ?

Comment: yes i did .... i have updated my question can you check

Comment: actually i have a input box i have fetched its value in controller now i want to call it on phtml file

Comment: Make sure you are getting the value in controller. For testing set the session value static like  Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEndBalance('my statis value');  and the print it in phtml

Comment: no i am not getting value in controller

Comment: i am getting value in controller via this public function getTextValueAction ()
    {
    $input_amount = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customer_creditone');
    echo $input_amount.'<br>';

    
    }

Comment: Then check why you are not getting the value

Comment: thanks for reply now i am getting value in phtml file once again thanks....

Comment: i upvote your answer ...

Comment: bro i want to store this value in variable what should i do`   Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEndBalance('my statis value');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51574/discussion-between-er-sarvesh-v-tiwari-and-arunendra).

Answer (score 3):

You can set variable to block and use that block to phtml file and get attribute value

Use below code in **controller** file:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock("modulename/blockname")->setYourattribute($value);
```

Use below code in **template** file:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("modulename/blockname")->getYourattribute();
```

Comment: i am using attribute bro ....i have fetched value from input box now i want to call it on phtml file

Comment: get val in controller and add above code in controller