# Magento 1.9: How to pass a variable from controller to setTemplate block?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have to pass a variable to a block `.phtml` file. I am setting layout in the controller by `setTemplate()` function. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please my answer it will help you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154123/how-to-pass-variable-to-phtml-file-in-magento/154145#154145

Answer (score 4):

Here I have a solution might work for you. We mostly use `setData()` method for pass variables from the controller to block.

```
$variableValue = 10000;
$block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('blockNameHere');
$block->setData('variable', '$variableValue')->setTemplate('pathto/block.phtml');
```

above `setData()` method will create a variable, and you can access this variable in the block file `block.phtml` you created. Use below code for getting the value of the variable.

```
echo $this->variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

simple example to pass a variable from Magento (template, controller, etc) file to a block with php code.

Call a block using the createBlock() method:

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('module/template_name')
->setData('key', 'some value')
->setTemplate('module/newblock.phtml')->toHtml();
```

The setData() method in the above code creates a variable, and you can access the variable with below code in the code that handles the block you created:

```
<?php
echo $this->key;
```